# Searach for the servernames in CSV by taking input from user python

Tags: python, csv

I have a server name, IP address, status and location in one CSV file. This has some 80K servers and need to write a program by either taking the `,` separted servernames or from file as input. It search for one by one server in CSV and print all the existing servers along with the IP address and not existing server list at the end of program.

I tried to do the below program but not getting the required output in else block.

```
import re,sys
search_item=raw_input()
search_item=search_item.split(,)
f="ss.csv"
for  i in search_item:
   for line in open(f,'r'):
      if re.search(i,line):
        array=line.split(',')
        print "%s|%s" %(array[2],array[3])
```

But not sure how to write else block and if given server name is `ss` and if it has `ss@xyz.com` in CSV. The condition should be true and print the subsequent columns.